# How to get sender's uri in spring rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, kotlin, spring-rest

I have a simple controller

```
@RestController 
class UploadController {
    val lastSenderUri: String = ""

    @GetMapping("/registerBlock")
    fun registerBlock() {
        // Here I want store sender's uri
        lastSenderUri = ???
    }
}
```

And I want store sender's URI in method `registerBlock`

How can I do it?

Comment: use HttpServletRequest as a parameter in the  registerBlock method and get required details from the request

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value in the referer header

```
@RestController 
class UploadController {

    @GetMapping("/registerBlock")
    fun registerBlock(@RequestHeader("referer") lastSenderUri: String?) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```